# Displays the number of times the numbers from 1 through 9 appear in a two-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays

We are to display the number of times the numbers from 1 through 9 appear in a two-dimensional array. We can't use map, vector, or anything advanced.

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
       //declare numbers array
       int numbers[5][3] = {{1, 2, 7},
                           {2, 5, 3},
                           {1, 9, 4},
                           {2, 6, 5},
                           {7, 2, 2}};
      //declare counts array
      int counts[9];

     //declare variable
     int digit  = 0;    //keeps track of numbers from 1 through 9

    while (digit <= 9)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
                //count the number of times the digit appears in the numbers 
                  array
                if (numbers[row][col] == digit)
                    counts[numbers[row][col]]++;
                //end if
            //end for
        //end for
       digit++;  //look for next digit
    } //end while

    //display counts
    for (int x = 1; x < 10; x++)
        cout << "The number " << x << " appears "
             << counts[x] << " time(s)." << endl;
    //end for

    cin.get();
    return 0;
    }   //end of main function
```

I can get it to show "The numbers 1 appears (a large number) time(s)." It will show that sentence 9 times with the 1 incrementing at each statement. The problem is the large number. How do I get it to show the correct number of times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you fix your first problem and initialize `int counts[9] = {0};`, you will still experience *Undefined Behavior* and end up attempting to access values beyond the end of your array bounds because declaring:

```
int counts[9] = {0};
```

Makes the valid indexes for counts `0 - 8` *not* `1 - 9`. So when you iterate `counts[x]` in:

```
for (int x = 1; x < 10; x++)
    cout << "The number " << x << " appears "
         << counts[x] << " time(s)." << endl;
```

You invoke *Undefined Behavior* attempting to read `counts[9]`. If you are going to use `x = 1; x < 10`, you need to access `counts[x-1]`.

A better approach is to loop `x = 0; x < 9` and just add `1` to:

```
    cout << "The number " << x + 1 << " appears "
```

The same indexing care must be taken when incrementing the values in your `counts` array to store the frequency of the numbers `1 - 9` (note: these are 1-above your actual array indexes `0 - 8`, which appears to largely be the intent of this exercise), e.g. you must subtract `1` when accounting for the frequency of occurrence of numbers `1 - 9` so that the proper corresponding index `0 - 8` hold the associated value, e.g.

```
            counts[numbers[i][j] - 1]++;    /* indexes are 0-8 */
```

Always looping over your array bounds (not outside them) will prevent issues such as this.

A short rewrite of the logic, and you could do something like:

```
#include <iostream>

#define NCOLS  3
#define NRANGE 9

using namespace std;

int main (void) {

    int numbers[][NCOLS] = {{1, 2, 7},
                            {2, 5, 3},
                            {1, 9, 4},
                            {2, 6, 5},
                            {7, 2, 2}},
        nrows = sizeof numbers / sizeof *numbers,   /* rows */
        counts[NRANGE] = {0};                   /* frequency */

    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)             /* fill counts */
        for (int j = 0; j < NCOLS; j++)
            if (1 <= numbers[i][j] && numbers[i][j] <= NRANGE)
                counts[numbers[i][j] - 1]++;    /* indexes are 0-8 */

    for (int x = 0; x < NRANGE; x++)            /* display counts */
        cout << "The number " << x + 1 << " appears "
                << counts[x] << " time(s)." << endl;

#if defined (_WIN32) || defined (_WIN64)
    cin.get();
#endif
}
```

(if you are using `cin.get();` to prevent the terminal from closing on windows, you should wrap that in preprocessor conditionals as that is unneeded on other OSs)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/frequency_array
The number 1 appears 2 time(s).
The number 2 appears 5 time(s).
The number 3 appears 1 time(s).
The number 4 appears 1 time(s).
The number 5 appears 2 time(s).
The number 6 appears 1 time(s).
The number 7 appears 2 time(s).
The number 8 appears 0 time(s).
The number 9 appears 1 time(s).
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int counts[9];
```

This will create the array, but it won't initialize the values, so you're getting undefined behavior! (The compiler is probably just giving you whatever bits were already there in memory, which likely evaluates to some very big numbers).

Instead, you want to initialize your counts to `0`:

```
int counts[9] = {0};
```